# Why "had" was used here

Tags: grammar

> Four days ago, just when they were nearing Dynize, an immense gale **had**
>   scattered his fleet. Dozens of transports and their heavily armed
>   escorts **had** been caught up in the storm. When it finally passed, the
>   Seaward **had** found itself all alone and blown a couple hundred miles
>   north of their rendezvous point on the Dynize shore. Styke **had** no way
>   of knowing how many of the ships **had** been lost, or how badly they’d
>   been dispersed. He didn’t know if half of his Lancers **had** drowned, or
>   been dashed against the shore, or if his entire army of twenty-five
>   hundred cavalry **had** already landed and was waiting impatiently for him
>   to arrive. Regardless, the Seaward sailed south at speed, hoping to
>   make up for lost time and avoid any Dynize warships along the way.

"Four days ago, just when they were nearing Dynize". After that they have used, "an immense gale had scattered his fleet". Instead of "an immense gale scattered his fleet. And then they have used "had" again and again. Why is that so?

Comment: The construction "had scattered" (and all the other "had"s) is the [past perfect tense](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/past-perfect). The reason it is used here is the most common reason for using the past perfect.

Comment: All of the things that *had* happened, happened ***before*** the thing in the final sentence (which also happened in the past). If *had* isn't used, it's possible they all happened at the same time as each other.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica: the fourth *had* is just in the past, not the past perfect (and it's correct that way).

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, you're right. I missed that one exception in my comment.